# EF5 model first - storing images

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

I'm designing a DB using VS2012 (EF5) by first creating a model. I can't find a way to store images - not an `image` type, nor `Binary` type. What can I use?

Comment: byte[] is what I have typically seen.

Comment: Do not store Images in DB especially if you are going to use EF , or you will get some serious performace hit , just store the file name

Comment: @sino how serious? can't I use lazy loading so I load the Image just when I want it?

Comment: Yes you can use lazy loading.  However, you will still get performance issues if you are planning on doing this to store the images for your site.  If its just an image here an there its not bad, but I wouldn't try to use it for a CMS.

Comment: @elyashiv: Very serious

Comment: Come on guys, it's perfectly OK to store images in the database, esp. when using FileStream (Sql Server). And there are techniques to prevent performance hits, like [table splitting](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/24/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you were using data first, you would end up with a byte array (byte[]), so that's what I would go with.

Picking Binary as the type in the model builder with create a byte[].

Comment: I know that, I just can't find the option in the model designer (VS2012)